# angularjs data binding object properties vs raw object

Tags: angularjs

I am reading a book about angularjs and in the chapter about "data binding best practices" it is written that it is best to bind to Object attributes, and not the raw object, but without any explanation of why it is better.

I'd like to to know what the advantage of the first example is

```
$scope.clock = [];
let updateClock = () => {
    $scope.clock.now = new Date();
    $timeout(() => {
        updateClock();
    }, 1000);
};
```

And the binding:

```
{{ clock.now }}
```

Vs.

```
let updateClock = () => {
    $scope.now = new Date();
    $timeout(() => {
        updateClock();
    }, 1000);
};
```

and the binding:

```
{{ now }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basic advantage of using object properties vs raw object is to :

- Group multiple raw  properties in one object
- While a raw object would serve as the solo property making it an object in itself

Look at the below code snippet of an object's multiple properties where there are two properties (now, next) associated with one object (clock):

```js
angular.module("app", []).controller("ctrl", function($scope, $timeout) {

  $scope.clock = {};
  let updateClock = () => {
    var dt = new Date();
    $scope.clock.now = new Date();
    $scope.clock.next = new Date(dt.setHours(dt.getHours() + 1));
    $timeout(() => {
      updateClock();
    }, 1000);
  };

  updateClock();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">

  <p>Clock Now : {{clock.now}}</p>
  <p>Clock Now + 1 hour : {{clock.next}}</p>
</body>
```